# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'navigation')

Tags: reactjs, next.js, redux-toolkit, swiper.js, rtk-query

Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'navigation')

```
onSwiper={(swiper) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
              swiper.params.navigation.prevEl = navigationPrevRef.current;
              swiper.params.navigation.nextEl = navigationNextRef.current;
              swiper.navigation.destroy();
              swiper.navigation.init();
              swiper.navigation.update();
            });
          }
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

This error means that `swiper` or `swiper.params` is undefined and `navigation` cannot be read from it.

You can check it by adding a console.log(swiper) and console.log(swiper.params) before the setTimeout.

Answer (score 0):

Add A If Condition
it worked for me

```
setTimeout(() => {
            // Override prevEl & nextEl now that refs are defined
            if (swiper.params) {
              swiper.params.navigation.prevEl = navigationPrevRef.current;
              swiper.params.navigation.nextEl = navigationNextRef.current;

              // Re-init navigation
              swiper.navigation.destroy();
              swiper.navigation.init();
              swiper.navigation.update();
            }
          }, 500);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).